# Hadoop jar: Unknown program

Tags: java, hadoop

I am running my program in hadoop.
I need to know how to set the path of my program in hadoop

`hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples*.jar NumberDriver input output1
Unknown program 'NumberDriver' chosen.`

Comment: What is your question? See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need the fully qualified class of `NumberDriver` within `hadoop-mapreduce-examples*.jar` (assuming it is there)

For example

```
$ hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples*.jar \
  org.apache.org.mapredule.examples.NumberDriver \
  input output1
```

Are you sure you are using the correct JAR file? I'm not able to find that class in the Hadoop source code.